# quick question for regex

Tags: regex, grep

I have a word list, but it has some words like East's

I need to find the words, those only contain a-z and A-Z, from a word list. How to do that.

I am using grep. What should I put after grep

```
grep *** myfile.txt
```

Thanks!

Comment: It would help us if you could share what tool you'll be using, e.g., Perl, grep, awk, sed, etc.

Comment: Depends what language you're using. Note that regex operates on strings, not on lists of strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The grep syntax is:

```
grep '^[[:alpha:]]\+$' input.txt
```

Documentation for grep's pattern syntax is [here](http://ss64.com/bash/grep2.html).

Answer (score 2):

The regexp you want is ^[a-zA-Z]+$

For grep:

```
vinko@parrot:~$ more a.txt
Hi
Hi Dude
Hi's
```

```
vinko@parrot:~$ egrep ^[a-zA-Z]+$ a.txt
Hi
```

In pseudocode:

```
 regexp = "^[a-zA-Z]+$";
 foreach word in list
      if regexp.matches(word)
          do_something_with(word)
```

Comment: I am sorry I forgot I am using grep

Answer (score 0):

```
[a-z]+
```

using the case insensitive option, or

```
[A-Za-z]+
```

without the case insensitive option.

Post the data and the langage for more help.

for grep

```
egrep -i '^[a-z]+$' wordlist.dat
```

i can't remember what metachars need escaping and not if it doesn't work, try \[a-z\]\+ or any similar combination!

Comment: I am sorry I forgot I am using grep

Comment: I tried egrep -i '[a-z]+' wordlist.dat, but it still output the words with ' sign.

Comment: hmm ofc it would now i think about it, just add ^ and $, `^[a-z]$`, this assers that all characters match the class, ^ is the start of line char and $ is end of line.

Answer (score 0):

Use `fgrep` if you want to match against a word list.

```
fgrep word_list_file myfile.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

GNU grep

```
grep -wEo "[[:alpha:]]+" file
```

Answer (score 0):

Or filter out all words that contain funnies

```
grep -v '[^a-zA-Z]'
```

Is there a prize for the shortest answer? :)

Note that there are portability differences between [[:alpha:]] and [A-Za-z]. [A-Za-z] works in more versions of grep, but [[:alpha:]] takes account of wide character environments and internationalization (accented characters for example when they are included in the locale).